# Java regex for Windows file path

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I'm trying to build a Java regex to search a .txt file for a Windows formatted file path, however, due to the file path containing literal backslashes, my regex is failing.

The .txt file contains the line:

```
C\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
```

However, some of the filenames in the text file are formatted like this:

```
C\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll (some developer stuff here...)
```

So I'm unable to use String.equals

To match this line, I'm using the regex:

```
filename = "C\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\ntdll.dll"
read = BufferedReader.readLine();

if (Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(filename), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(read).find()) {
```

I've tried escaping the literal backslashes, using the replace method, i.e:

```
filename.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

However, this is failing to find, I'm guessing this is because I need to further escape the backslashes after the Pattern has been built, I'm thinking I might need to escape upto an additional four backslashes, i.e:

```
Pattern.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

However, each time I try, the pattern doesn't get matched.  I'm certain it's a problem with the backslashes, but I'm not sure where to do the replacement, or if there's a better way of building the pattern.

I think the problem is further being compounded as the replaceAll method also uses a regex, with means the pattern will have it's own backslashes in there, to deal with the case insensitivity.

Any input or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your original string will trigger a compile failure

Comment: Yep, sorry, let me fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're attempting to to a direct comparison of `String` against another. For exact matches, you could do (

```
if (read.equalsIgnoreCase(filename)) {
```

of simply

```
if (read.startsWith(filename)) {
```

Comment: Its better than fighting with java's bizarre `\\`

Comment: The problem is that some of the file paths aren't identical in case.  The txt file might contain C:\Windows\syswow64\ntdll.dll, and the input I'm given contains the exact upper/lower case mix.

Comment: Or thinking about it, might it just be easier to read in the line from the file, convert it to lowercase, then just search for it?

Comment: Ahh yes, of course.  I'd forgotten about that one.  I'll go back and see if it solves my problem, thanks!

Comment: I've just updated the question as to why I need to use a regex.

Comment: seems like you have some additional characters after the filename on some lines. Why not use `substring` to extract the filename from the beginning of line?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

> While reading each line from the file, replace '\' by '\\'.

Then :

```
String lLine = "C\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\ntdll.dll";
Pattern lPattern = Pattern.compile("C\\\\Windows\\\\SysWOW64\\\\ntdll\\.dll");
Matcher lMatcher = lPattern.matcher(lLine);
if(lMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(lMatcher.group());
}

lLine = "C\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\ntdll.dll (some developer stuff here...)";
lMatcher = lPattern.matcher(lLine);
if(lMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(lMatcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage will be:

```
String filename = "C\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\ntdll.dll";
String file = filename.replace('\\', ' ');
```

Comment: I don't understand?  Why would I replace the original backslashes with spaces?

Comment: I have just given the example for the correct usage